# Azure AD B2C - Password Reset on First SignIn scenario only possible via Custom Policy?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My goal is to create an Azure AD B2C User via the graph API with a password of my choosing and then for the user to go through a password reset experience after their first login.

Firstly, how does one get a user into a state that would trigger the password reset upon their next login? If I go [reset password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6GxM.png) in Azure and then use the generated password at sign-in, I get a "This password has expired" error. Presuming it's a password policy issue, I've been toying with the Graph API like:

```
user.PasswordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration,DisableStrongPassword";
user.PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
{
 ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
};
```

My Graph API access is successful but I still can't get around the error:

> "This password has expired"

The second issue, is how exactly do I set up a user flow that achieves this? I would prefer an on-screen password reset experience instead of the email-based experience.

The most promising direction appears to be switching from User Flows to Custom Policies where there is an example of how to achieve my goal: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon.

My question is - is this only possible to achieve via the Custom Policy approach?

Answer (score 1):

Custom policy, as per the sample you linked, is the right solution. Or use the User Flow v1 flows, which are pretty limited, they support the built-in `forceChangePassword` flag.